# inserting DOM created forms into included PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I have included a PHP file with my HTML layout into a PHP file and am trying to manipulate the DIV's of the HTML layout with javascript. My question is; how do I insert my DOM-created form into the DIV of the included PHP file? 
 
Here's what I have so far.

```
<?php
include_once('../index.php');
?>
<script>
/*var databox = document.getElementById("databox");
databox.innerHTML = "I added this text dynamically.";
var newform = databox.createElement("FORM");
document.getElementById("newform").name="form";
document.body.insertBefore(newform, databox); */


var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Since at javascript run-time your `div` is already created and included in the 'current' file, you could just refers to it via its `id`, its `name` or even a `class` then via some Javascript DOM manipulation 'append' the `form` to it. In PHP it doesn't matter in what file the DOM/HTML element is, as long as the file its in is include to the executing PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of good 'ways' to do this. But since you seems to use pure Javascript and seems comfortable using `appendChild()` here is what I propose with some explanations:

First lets setup a context:

Lets say we have **index.php** like so:

```
//Put DOCTYPE, HTML tag, Head Tag and other stuff here
<body>
    <div id="IamID"></div>//I will receive the form.
//Site note I intentionally didn't put the end of the body tag.
```

Now lets say we have something like this **form.php** file that goes like this:

```
<?php
include_once('index.php');
?>
<script>
/*var databox = document.getElementById("databox");
databox.innerHTML = "I added this text dynamically.";
var newform = databox.createElement("FORM");
document.getElementById("newform").name="form";
document.body.insertBefore(newform, databox); */

var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(s);
</script>
</body>
//Note end of body tag here.
```

When executing **form.php** the server will execute all the PHP code before rendering the page that it will send to the browser. The file receive by the browser will be the concatenation of the two file above like this:

```
//Put DOCTYPE, HTML tag, Head Tag and other stuff here
<body>
    <div id="IamID"></div>//I will receive the form.
//Site note I intentionally didn't put the end of the body tag.
<script>
/*var databox = document.getElementById("databox");
databox.innerHTML = "I added this text dynamically.";
var newform = databox.createElement("FORM");
document.getElementById("newform").name="form";
document.body.insertBefore(newform, databox); */

var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"username");

var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(s);
</script>
</body>
//Note end of body tag here.
```

And since Javascript execute at the browsers level you should be able to refer to HTML markups or even other Javascript function define in **index.php** because your browser 'sees' the two file as one.

So to answer your question, you could just add something like this to your Javascript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById("IamID");
div.appendChild(f);
```

Other little side note:

There is a sh*t tone of way to add a DOM element to your HTML markup. Feel free to use whatever method you feel comfortable using. (I used appendChild because you seem to use it a lot in your code).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, this helped a lot and I've got it working now. How can I find alternative ways to do this by the way, for educational reasons?

Comment: Well some will down vote me for this but I think that to start and learn the basics you could go to http://www.w3schools.com/ but be aware that they often have bad example and/or some errors. But for educational purpose it should do the trick